# How will I pass parameters such as, user id in hyper link?

Tags: html, email, flask, outlook, hyperlink

I have a HTML page where there is one hyperlink. This html email will be sent to users via outlook (I have written the mail function using flask python) and when users will click on hyperlink on the email body, it will eventually open another page. This page will be same but, the content of the page will be different for different users based on the users' email id.

Right now, my requirement is to pass the user email ID through hyperlink so, I can display different content based on email ID. Can it be done through hyperlink? As, you know that outlook uses Microsoft Word as rendering engine so, will it be difficult to pass parameter through hyperlink ?

Or, can I pass the email ID through my flask function while sending the mails?

My flask function which will send mail to outlook is below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mail import Mail, Message


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    MAIL_SERVER='My Company SMTP MAIL SERVER',
    MAIL_PORT=My Company SMTP PORT NUMBER,
    # MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
    MAIL_USERNAME='XXXXX.YYYY@mycompanyname.com',
)
mail = Mail(app)


@app.route('/')
def mailSend():
    try:
        recipeint_emails = fetch_recipient_emails
        msg = Message("Send Mail Tutorial!",
                      sender="XXXXX.YYYY@mycompanyname.com",
                      recipients=recipeint_emails)
        msg.html = render_template('linkPage.html')
        mail.send(msg)
        return 'Mail sent!'
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e))
        print(e)
        return 'error'
```

The linkPage.html will contain the hyperlink which is mentioned below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hyperlinkdemo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://hyperlinkflask.azurewebsites.net/helloworld" target="_blank">Visit Dynamic Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you maybe share some code with us?

Comment: i have added just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask` has already a builtin function `url_for` to generate properly a link with extra parameters. Refer to this [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for)

## UPDATE

- it's recommended to choose the accurate name for routes
- it's recommended to use snake_case when naming views
- i recommend you to refer to the official `Flask-Mail` [doc](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#bulk-emails) section `Bulk Mail`

```
@app.route('/bulk-email')
def bulk_mail():

    [..]

    # Get all users first
    with mail.connect() as conn:
        for user in users:
            msg = Message(subject="Tutorial",
                          sender="XXXXX.YYYY@mycompanyname.com",
                          recipients=[user.email])
            # pass dynamically the user to the template
            msg.html = render_template('linkPpage.html', user=user)
            conn.send(msg)
```

in `linkPage.html` template you can do

```
<p>Dear {{ user.username }},</p>
<p>
  <a href = "{{ url_for('link_tutorial', user_id=user.id, _external=True) }}">Open Link tutorial</a>
</p> //added double quotation
```

you have to implement the logic of `link_tutorial` function, when user click on the link it will be redirected to your app to show him a customized page / tutorial:

```
@app.route('/link-tutorial/<int:user_id>')
def link_tutorial(user_id):
    # fetch the user with the given user_id and render the right template for him.
    [..]
    return render_template('tutorial.html')
```

finally, i would recommend you using `celery` an asynchronous task queue to handle the bulk email more efficiently than `Flask-Mail`, because sending mail is a blocking task and your app will be very slow and not responsive.

Comment: thank you for you response, will this hyperlink work on outlook email body? As, i already mentioned that my mail function will send mail to users using outlook.

Comment: @DebarthaMitra i updted my post

Comment: @DebarthaMitra oulook, gmail .. have a very strong automated processes to filter email by header, body or content .. but if they detect that attachments are specious (virus, executable code even js script ..) or links (fishing ..) they will mark the email as danger and block content. in you case, outlook will mostly mark the bulk emails as spam, to void that try to use Sendgrid, mailshimp for transnational emails via api.

Comment: thank you, your solution worked, let me look into the apis that you have mentioned.

Comment: @DebarthaMitra this is a starting point : https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-twilio-sendgrid-to-send-emails-from-python-flask-applications and https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/sendgrid-flask-mail, also you will find 3rd packges on pypi